# php Msql search multiple columns

Tags: php

Hello I got the below code from Youtube tutorial and it works if I search for a string that only exists in 1 column. If I combine search for something that is in two different columns then I get no results.
For example if Jack is in column 1 and Rabbit in column 2, If I search for "Jack Rabbit" then I get no results at all, If I search for "Jack" then it works, same for "Rabbit".

I know the fix is in the line below but when I changed the line according to other posts here on stackoverflow that I searched for, I got errors because their code was a bit different than mine.

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnOne LIKE '%$searchq%' OR columnTwo LIKE '%$searchq%'  ") or die("Could not search!");
```

Whole search code below

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "Name_Name", "Password") or die("Could not connect");
mysql_select_db("Name_Databse") or die("Could not find db!");
$output = ' ' ;
//collect

if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $searchq = $_POST['search'];
        $searchq = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i", " ", $searchq);

        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnOne LIKE '%$searchq%' OR columnTwo LIKE '%$searchq%'  ") or die("Could not search!");
        $count = mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($count == 0) {
        $output = 'There was no such results!';

        }else{
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $id = $row['id'];
            $aHref = $row['aHref'];
            $columnOne = $row['columnOne'];
            $columnTwo = $row['columnTwo'];
            $inputDiv = $row['inputDiv'];
            $image = $row['image'];


$output .= '<a href="' . $aHref . '.html" class="link"> <div class="Poster">' .  ' <div class="columnOne">' . $columnOne . ' </div> <div class="columnTwo">' . $columnTwo . ' </div>    <div class="inputDiv">' . $inputDiv . ' </div>  <div class="image"><img src="' . $image . '.jpg"/>' . '</div> </div></a>';


            }
    }   

}


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>              
        <title> Search </title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Styler.css'/>

</head>
<body>



                    <form action='search.php' method='post' style="margin: 0 0 25px;">
                    <input type='text' name='search' size='50' placeholder="Search here"/>
                    <input type='submit' value='Search' />
                    </form>

                        <?php print("$output"); ?> 





</script>               
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the specific MySQL error that you are getting ?

Comment: Well, there you go. This is the classic: *"The left hand doesn't know what the right hand is doing or holding"*. You'll need to use `explode()`. Ya can't have your cake `AND` eat it too ;-)

Comment: Try to include `mysql_error()` to check if there is any kind of error. Like this: `or die("Could not search:" .mysql_error());`

Comment: @ Maximus2012 I am not getting any errors with my current code, but with the code that I tried earlier I got a code that referred to row 15 which was $count = mysql_num_rows($query); .  @ I only got 1 hand so... :P

Comment: @bcesars thanks for input I tried it but got no errors, just got "There was no such results!"

Comment: If one column has "Jack" while the other has "Rabbit", then you can't expect your code to work in order to find what is being queried as "Jack Rabbit". Your code works exactly as written. You'll need to find another way; add a second input, or `explode()` the words.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks I'm watching a tutorial right now in order to "implement" the explode into the code :)

Comment: You're welcome. Have a look at an answer below. Kinda looks promising. Give that a go and see.

Comment: yeah I'll go with that, should work fine with my work and less work for my brain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about combining both columns and searching that as well:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE columnOne LIKE '%$searchq%' OR columnTwo LIKE '%$searchq%' OR CONCAT_WS(' ', columnOne, columnTwo) LIKE  '%$searchq%'
```

This would only work though if they search for "columnOne + [space] + columnTwo". If you want to be able to match ANY word they enter (i.e., searching for "Jack W. Rabbit" still matches), then you would use the exploding method as previously suggested.

Comment: *...even better.* It's "thee" solution. Good job ;-)